# Problems with installing stock ROM for Nexus S

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, rom-flashing, stock-android, signature-error

I'm trying to install a stock Nexus S ROM from Google's site, but I keep getting the error `E:signature verification failed`

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Download the correct factory image [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#soju), unpack it, and run *flash-all.sh* to reset to stock. You must boot your Nexus to fastboot mode beforehand and also have an unlocked bootloader first (*fastboot oem unlock*). After the flash is done, relock your bootloader again (*fastboot oem lock*).

Comment: How do I run flash-all.sh from the phone?

Comment: @meds You don't run it from the phone, you have to connect via your PC using adb and fastboot. This a [guide](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=imho) for setting up adb and fastboot on Windows. Alternatively, you may want to use this [One Click Method](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1669093)